# Discord js check if a user joined or left the voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How can i check if a user joined or left a vocal channel with the new version of discordj (v12.x)?

```
 client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
        if(userJOined){
         //do somethings
        }else{
         //do something else if the user left
       }

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [`VoiceStates`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/VoiceState) have a [`channelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channelID) property: the ID of the [`VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/VoiceChannel) they're already in or `null`. If `oldState.channelID` is `null` and `newState.channelID` isn't, you'll know that the member joined a voice channel. If it's the other way around, you'll know the member *left* a voice channel.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (newState, oldState) => {
 if (newState.channelID && !oldState.channelID) {
  console.log('Someone joined');
  // ...
 } else if (oldState.channelID && !newState.channelID) {
  console.log('Someone left');
  // ...
 } else {
  console.log('Neither of the two actions occured');
  // ...
 }
});
```